# HawtIO Dashboard Diagram of Camel Routes and flow of all the processors in it

Tags: apache-camel, hawtio

I saw that HawtIO has a Dashboard that shows the flow of the route into each processor in it and the count for each call made.I checked into the apache Camel,I believe you are reading the JVM for getting the metrics of the Routes and the processors in it but what I don't understand is how are you able to construct this block diagram and the exact flow into each processor.[image].

Can someone help me out with this.I am trying to build a similar UI such as hawtIO for specifically on Apache Camel and I want to know how it can be done?

Comment: Hawt.io is open source project. You can check how it is done in https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio

Comment: Can you pinpoint to the Class or the Package where it was implemented because there are so many sub projects in this repo..

Comment: And you can look at the source code for hawtio v2 as its separated into separate git repos so its easier to navigate - https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio-integration/tree/master/plugins/camel

Comment: btw instead of building your own Camel UI you can also contribute and work on hawtio.

Answer (score 3):

Hawtio is getting its application insights with [Jolokia](https://jolokia.org/). Jolokia is providing a HTTP bridge to JMX. So, in other words, all the informations you need are exposed by Camel MBeans via JMX.

So, you have two options to get hold of Camel's JMX info:

- base your own UI on Jolokia as well.
- go old school and use a JSR-160 connector.

Comment: Yes ,Its true that jolokia provides the JMX values of all the camel mbeans but how can we able to group, all the processors pertaining to a particular routeId into the above flow diagram?

Comment: I assume they piece it together from the information in the MBeans - I had a look at the MBean information and there seems to be all you need including Route Names.

Comment: yes there is a jmx operation that can dump any/all routes in xml format, so we just parse the xml as a dom tree and do a little bit of customization to draw the diagram.

Comment: And for JSR-160 don't ever go down that route. Use jolokia over HTTP. Then from the web console its just a regular HTTP/REST call. And you can use modern web framework such as angular or whatnot